# Cypress: Button not visible when checking a checkbox through Cypress

Tags: angular, cypress

I am developing a web application using Angular. There is a table that has checkboxes for
each line.

When I check one of the checkboxes, action buttons such as "View" or "Delete" show up at the bottom on the screen. However, when I check it by Cypress with the following command, the buttons don't show up.

`cy.get('[ng-reflect-message="16"]').parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').check({force: true})`

How should I do to show up the buttons on the screen using Cypress?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you see the checkbox at once when you load the page? Or the checkbox appears after say 4 seconds (default timeout for cypress commands)? And also please check whether you are using the correct locator.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer.
The checkbox is normal one(input type="checkbox"）.
1st one got an error below.

```
Timed out retrying after 4000ms: cy.trigger() failed because this element is not visible:

<input type="checkbox">

This element <input> is not visible because it has an effective width and height of: 0 x 0 pixels.

Fix this problem, or use {force: true} to disable error checking.Learn more
```

Then, I added {force: true} to trigger part as below and ran it. No errors occurred this time but the buttons still did not show up.

```
      cy.get('[ng-reflect-message="16"]')
        .parent()
        .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
        .check({force: true})
        .trigger('change', {force: true})
```

I executed 2nd one as well. No errors occurred and the buttons did not show up.

Are there anything else I can try?

Comment: There are two events this type of input can handle (ref [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox)) - change and input. It would be worth trying  `.trigger('input', {force: true})`. Otherwise, I suspect there's another element receiving the event and in it's handler sets the checkbox `checked = true` and also enables the buttons.

Comment: I found out that span tag inside of the input tag has the trigger of the buttons. I checked the checkbox and clicked the tag using Cypress command below, then the buttons showed up! Thank you so much to help me!

    cy.get('[ng-reflect-message="16"]')
      .parent()
      .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
      .check({force: true})

    cy.get('[ng-reflect-message="16"]')
      .parent()
      .find('span[class="checkmark"]')
      .click()

Answer (score 0):

With Angular you often have to trigger a change event along with the check, so perhaps

```js
cy.get('[ng-reflect-message="16"]')
  .parent()
  .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
  .check({force: true})
  .trigger('change')
```

If it's a `mat-checkbox` a click will do the trick

```js
cy.get('[ng-reflect-message="16"]')
  .parent()
  .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
  .click({force: true})
```